# Switch returning default

Tags: php

Sorry if my code is bad-written, I'm a beginner in this.
So, I have an array filled with 6 values :

```
 $attacks= ['attack1', 'attack2', 'attack3', 'attack4', 'attack5', 'attack6'];
```

I also have a `foreach` statement with an `isset` statement made this way :

```
        foreach ($attacks as $atkarray) {
        if (isset($_POST[$atkarray])) {
```

In case you wonder, the `if` is working properly when the user select one of the values available.
Now, I have set a `switch` statement after the `if` to modify a value right after depending on the value :

```
                switch ($_POST[$atkarray]) {
                case 'attack4':
                    $attackmult = 3;
                    break;
                case 'attack5':
                    $attackmult = 3;
                    break;
                case 'attack6':
                    $attackmult = 6;
                    break;
                default:
                    $attackmult = 1;
                    break;
            }
```

Now the problem is that even if I chose "attack4" , "5" or "6" I will ALWAYS have the default value (1) and I frankly don't know why.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: How are you verifying the value that you think you are getting?

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't understood the question you asked me. If you are talking about security issues, this is not a problem.

Comment: you have `$attacks` but you loop through `$atkarrays`. just a copy-paste error?

Comment: Oops, you are right, my bad !

Comment: I think he meant how you verified that your `$_POST` contains any of those values in your switch/case-statement. You only have three different case-statements, while you have 6 different attacks in your array. If the post contains attack1, attack2 or attack3, you will get the default.

Comment: for development purposes, switch on `error_reporting` to check for error messages, output `$_POST` to see if it actually contains what you think

Comment: The other cases i didn't write are in "default", isn't ?

Comment: Yes, and since you're saying that you only get the default, make sure that your POST-data for the other attacks exist. Do a `var_dump($_POST);`.

Comment: Right now, you're actually expecting to get post data like this: `['attack1' => 'attack1', ...]`. You could probably just do: `switch($atkarray)` instead.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson nailed it, I guess.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson got it right , this is actually what I wanted, I'm not quite used to this kind of things. Thanks you, and to everyone who helped me too !